# Iframe content not top 0 and left 0, why?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an online store where menus are hosted in another domain, so I bring them using iframes.

Website is [www.paulinhomotos.com.br](http://www.paulinhomotos.com.br)

What happens is that the content from iframe is not at top 0 left 0. Do you guys know why and how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

This is a screenshot showing the issue.
http://prntscr.com/6zim8q
[image]
Thanks!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Because the menu isn't top left on the original page

Answer (score 0):

Add *CSS* properties for the `iframe`

```
iframe{
  border: none;
}
```

or `iframe` tag includes `frameborder="0"`

like this

```
<iframe src="http://paulinhomotos1.hospedagemdesites.ws/menus/capacetes/menucapacetes.htm" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```